# Running unit tests from a command line

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm working on a suite of application that interact with many websites and api's. I have created unit tests that test this code.

As it's beyond my control, I want to know as soon as sites / api's change and the code stops working so I can fix and would like to run the tests periodically against the assemblies running. How can I run the tests outside of VS?

I'd like the option of testing on Linux mono too.

Comment: @Timwor the default with RC 2017.

Answer (score 3):

You can use MsTest from the [command line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx):

Example:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\mstest" /testcontainer:C:\MyTestProject\bin\debug\MyTestProject.dll /resultsfile:C:\TestResults\results.trx
```

(Full list of command line switches on the link above)

This is set to Visual Studio 2015, for 2017 just make sure you have the right version number, I believe 15.0

Comment: and how can i test on linux with mono?

Comment: Running mstest in mono, https://sashadu.wordpress.com/2016/06/05/c-mono-and-unit-testing/ someone seems to have written a custom runner.

Comment: What about through Ubuntu shell?

Answer (score 1):

MSTest has been deprecated, you'll want to invoke VSTest from the [command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2022)